# How to increase speed of GameObject?

Tags: unity

I'm making pong game in unity3d with monodevelop(c#). I want to increase speed of ball when it touch ends of paddle corner.

my ball script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ball : MonoBehaviour {


    public float InitialSpeed=1.0f;


    void Start () {
    float  xDir=Random.Range(-1.0f,1.0f);
        rigidbody.AddForce( new Vector3(xDir,-1.0f,0)*InitialSpeed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more infos about your ball. Is it a rigidbody? Does it have a script attached? Or is both the case? How do you currently check for collisions? How do you determine the speed (if you do, depending on your implementation it is not necessary)? Generally speaking, describe what you have so you can get a solution that fits to what you have. I alone can think of multiple solutions which some of might have great impact on your future project.

Comment: sorry about that & thanks @Larethian for your advice.plz see my edited post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want like this.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    float velo=collision.rigidbody.velocity.magnitude;
    Vector3 V3=collision.rigidbody.velocity;
    V3.x = (collision.transform.position.x - transform.position.x)*8;
    collision.rigidbody.velocity = V3;
    if(collision.rigidbody.velocity.magnitude < velo)
    {
        collision.rigidbody.velocity *= velo/collision.rigidbody.velocity.magnitude;
    }
}
```

Add this code into your script.

Comment: Now I understood this code.& It works for me thanks ....[kajal](http://www.variyasoftsolutions.com/unity3d.html)

Comment: Your welcome. Good luck for your project.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you are in a 2D plane,speed has is created by 2 separate vectors (because you can move on the x and y axis).If you want to increase the speed of an object which has a certain direction increase/decrease the value for the dimension you want to have your speed increased into.

Comment: Just the one vector, with two components.